# babel-polyfill adding 85kb to bundle size using webpack

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I have an ES6 React app that is being bundled with webpack and using babel. I have a dev and prod webpack config. The prod version uses DedupePlugin, OccurenceOrderPlugin, UglifyJsPlugin and sets the NODE_ENV to production. I'm also shimming react-lite in place of react in prod. The prod bundle size is around 70kb.

I've recently added babel-polyfill to both my dev and prod webpack configs. In prod, babel-polyfill adds around 85kb the my bundle size. That seems strange because I see little to no impact from babel-polyfill in other projects.

I'm simply adding it like so:

```
entry: ['babel-polyfill','./app.js'],
```

I've run webpack-bundle-size-analyzer, and the bundle is size is mostly due to babel-polyfill.

Any ideas?

Comment: `babel-polyfill` takes space, there's not much of a way to avoid it unless you want to manually include just pieces of the polyfill.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I have babel-polyfill in other projects and the prod builds seem to be affected very little by it. Doesn't 85kb seem a bit excessive?

Comment: Perhaps something in your other projects was already loading it, so when you added it, it didn't add much more? 85kb doesn't seem that bad to me given all that it's doing. You could certainly make your own build of `core-js` if you wanted though. It obviously depends on your usecase, but for most the size difference probably wouldn't give you much though.